# Using Jasmine to test Angular 2 App with Router

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular2-routing

I have an Angular 2 application that uses the Router to navigation to different pages. I want to test if routing is done correctly from one component to another, either by calling a function that contains `this.router.parent.navigate` or "clicking" a UI component to trigger the navigation.

**First Question:** Is Jasmine the framework a good choice to go with testing this or should Jasmine be left to strictly for unit testing each component by itself?

**Second Question:** If Jasmine is capable or is a good choice for accomplishing such a task, how do I go about creating a test for my component that takes in a Router (when it is done at the root for the app) and assign `RouteConfig` paths to that router? Below is my code attempt... but of course it fails.

```
describe('MyApp', () => {

    beforeEachProviders(() => [Router]);

    it('should have name property set', inject([Router], (router: Router) => {
        let myApp = new MyApp(router);
        expect(myApp).toBeDefined();
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine framework would be a good choice. The following test sample could be scaled to your application to ensure routing is done correctly, from one component to another (@angular/router 3.4.7).

I have recently wrote an article about this on my personal blog: https://medium.com/burak-tasci/using-jasmine-framework-to-test-angular-router-b568a232efed

First of all, let's import the dependencies we will need in this test:

```
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
```

Then, let's create a `TestBootstrapComponent` which contains the `router-outlet` - used to bootstrap the test app; and a `TestComponent`.

You won't need to create different components for each route. A dummy test component is more than enough.

```
@Component({ template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>' })
export class TestBootstrapComponent {}

@Component({ template: '' })
export class TestComponent {}
```

Now, you will need to import these components to the app.

Keeping in mind that components can only be imported by one module, you should create a `shared module` and import components there - which could be imported by any `feature modules` in case of need:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [TestComponent,TestBootstrapComponent],
    imports: [RouterTestingModule]
})
export class TestSharedModule { }
```

And then, you'll need to provide `routes`:

```
export const testRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: TestComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'about',
                component: TestComponent
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'change-language/:languageCode',
        component: TestComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

Finally, it's time to prepare the module configuration for testing purposes:

```
// test module configuration for each test
export const testModuleConfig = () => {
    // reset the test environment before initializing it.
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();

    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting())
        .configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                TestSharedModule,
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(testRoutes),
            ]
        });
};
```

After all, testing the route navigation across pages is as easy as below:

```
describe('Some service',
    () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            testModuleConfig();
        });

        it('should be able to navigate to `/`',
            fakeAsync(() => {
                const injector = getTestBed();
                const router = injector.get(Router);

                const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestBootstrapComponent);
                fixture.detectChanges();

                // initial navigation
                router.navigate(['/'])
                    .then(() => {
                        expect(router.url).toEqual('/');
                    });
            }));
});
```